# Octave - symbolic package using old version of sympy

Tags: octave

I am trying to use symbolic package in Octave (4.2.2). When I try to load the package, I receive the following error:
"Symbolic pkg v2.8.0: error: SymPy version 1.1.1 found but is too old (1.2 required)"
But when I checked, I understand that somehow newer sympy (version 1.3) is yes installed:
"(base) shlomo@shlomo-MS:~$ pip show sympy
Name: sympy
Version: 1.3
Summary: Computer algebra system (CAS) in Python
Home-page: http://sympy.org
Author: SymPy development team
Author-email: sympy@googlegroups.com
License: BSD"
How to force Octave to recognize (newer) SymPy that is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Find the version 1.3 it doesn't find, and the version 1.1.1 it finds, note where version 1.1.1 is located, wipe it out, move version 1.3 where version 1.1.1 is.

There are more delicate ways in case that was an important host, but that's going to be just alright for you. Hopefully.